# Debugging asp classic on IIS6

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, asp-classic, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to debug an old asp web site on a windows server.
actualy I don't have any project files (there is no visual studio project file), what I have is only web pages in a directory ... I can run this latter on a IIS6 and everything works fine, the problem is that when I try to run those pages in a debugging mode nothing happens!
I enbabled the debugging mode on the IIS and I attached this latter's process to the visual studio (I'm using VS2005) I set the breack points... but nothing happens even if I ran those pages code the compile doesn't stop!!
I saw several pages talking about this topic... but I wasn't able to find a solution... do you have any idea?
(I want to add that the web pages, the IIS and the Visual studio ide are on the same server and I'm connected with the administrator session)

Comment: Classic asp doesn't use compiled code - it's executed at runtime.  It existed long before the concept of the VS project, you just start with an empty root folder and add files to it.  The usual way to debug Classic is to work through the error messages it sends to the browser

Comment: You will have to go old school and manually display variables to the screen e.g. Response.write somevariable followed by a response.end to stop processing at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you when attach to set it to attach to Script code only and the break points must be within server-side code.